# Using apply() on single column in matrix in R

Tags: r

I would like to replace a complicated for loop using apply() functions.

The first thing I would like to figure out is how to use apply() on a matrix with 100 columns when I would only like to apply it to the first column. Is this possible?

For example:

```
for (i in 1:100){ if (runif(1,0,1)<0.01) { a[i,1]<-3-b[i,1] } }
```

How can I translate this to apply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `i` is used in more than place, `apply` is not the appropriate tool for your example.  Instead, you can use vectorized code:

```
a[, 1] <- if (runif(1,0,1) < 0.01) 3 - b[, 1] else a[, 1]
```

Note that if you want a different random outcome for each row, then you need to draw `nrow(a)` numbers and use the vectorized `ifelse`:

```
a[, 1] <- ifelse(runif(nrow(a), 0, 1) < 0.01,  3 - b[, 1], a[, 1])
```

Answer (score 5):

1.`apply` is designed to be used on matrices or arrays, whereas one particular column is a vector and considering `apply` family functions instead that would be more wise to use `mapply` or `sapply`:

```
# By passing b[, 1]. Two options
v <- sapply(b[, 1], function(x) if(runif(1, 0 ,1) < 0.01) 3 - x else NA)
v <- sapply(b[, 1], function(x) ifelse(runif(1, 0 ,1) < 0.01, 3 - x, NA))
a[!is.na(v), 1] <- v[!is.na(v)]

# By going through indices
a[, 1] <- sapply(1:nrow(b), function(x) 
  if(runif(1, 0, 1) < 0.01) 3 - b[x, 1] else a[x, 1])

# Using mapply to avoid problems related to NAs
mapply(function(x, y) ifelse(runif(1, 0, 1) < 0.01, 3 - y, x), a[, 1], b[, 1])
```

However, if you insist on using `apply` then, as Roman Luštrik noted, you have to make it look as a matrix, i.e. not to "drop" the dimensions by using `drop = FALSE`:

```
a[, 1] <- apply(b[, 1, drop = FALSE], 1, function(x) 
  if(runif(1, 0, 1) < 0.01) 3 - x else NA)
# This returns NAs to make it simpler for now
```

2.As noted by flodel, you have to try to use vectorization whenever it is possible. In your example this is possible since `runif` can generate `nrow(b)` numbers at a time and there is a vectorized version of `if`, that is `ifelse`

```
a[, 1] <- ifelse(runif(nrow(b), 0, 1) < 0.01,  3 - b[, 1], a[, 1])
```

And the final approach without `if` and `ifelse` would be

```
idx <- runif(100, 0, 1) < 0.01
a[idx, 1] <- 3 - b[idx, 1]
```

Comment: Outputting `NA` is a way to avoid the difficulty. I think the right `*apply` tool to replicate exactly what the OP is after would be `mapply`. Would make a nice addition to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, all you need to do is pass on the only one column.

```
set.seed(357)
my.data <- data.frame(x = runif(10), y = runif(10), z = runif(10))
apply(my.data[, 1, drop = FALSE], MARGIN = 2, FUN = mean)

        x 
0.5234919
```